# How to authentificate a IIS .NET User in an ASP.NET MVC 5 Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I need to rewrite a Sliverlight Application into a ASP.NET MVC 5 application. The User Accounts are stored as a ".NET User" in the IIS:

[image: IIS]

I think this Database is related to it:

[image: DB]

I assume, that there is some technologie build in in ASP.NET, that is for managing this users. Something like `NetUser.Authentificate(username, password)`

How ever, I can not find some reference. I am sure, I am searching with the wrong keywords.

Can you point me on the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the database tables, your old application used Membership Provider.

Membership Provider was shipped with ASP.Net 2.0, and more than a decade old already.

You have two solutions -

1. Migrate old data to new ASP.Net Identity 2 tables. It is a prefer solution, but you need to understand how those tables work. [Here](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/migrations/migrating-an-existing-website-from-sql-membership-to-aspnet-identity) is the example. ***Note***: the article is for ASP.Net Identity 1 (but you get the idea).
2. The second method is a quick and dirty way. You call ASP.Net Membership Provider's methods manually to Authenticate and Authorize user inside ASP.Net MVC 5. You can read those methods [here](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/membership/validating-user-credentials-against-the-membership-user-store-cs).

For example,

```
if(Model.IsValid)
{
   if(Membership.ValidateUser(model.Username, model.Password))
   { 
      // User is valid
   }
}
```

Comment: Ouch. Sha1 :D. Defintive need a upgrade. Thank you :)